# Use infinispan 7 for wildfly 8.1.0

Tags: wildfly, infinispan

in Wildfly 8.1.0, infinispan 6.0.2.Final is integrated, but I want to use newer version of Infinispan, 7.0.0.final, how can I configure wildfly or my pom.xml/jboss-deployment-structure.xml to use external infinispan 7.0.0.Final, not its own infinispan (6.0.2.Final). Thank you.

Comment: The simplest thing would be to use Wildfly 9....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create w [JBOSS Module](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Home) for Infinispan 7.

Go to: `%WILDFLY_HOME%\modules\system\layers\base\org\infinispan\` and copy the `\main` folder and rename it to for example `\version7`.

Inside this folder delete the infinispan 6 jar and place the infinispan 7 jar.

Then edit the `module.xml` and replace `infinispan-core-6.0.2.Final.jar` with the filename of the infinispan 7 jar. 
Then edit `<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.infinispan">` by adding a slot like `version7`.

Finally in `jboss-deployment-strucutre.xml` reference infinispan with the slot `version7`.