# Wildfly 10.0.0.CR4, how to migrate to Infinispan 8.1?

Tags: migration, wildfly, infinispan

I want to migrate my Wildfly server to a newer version of Infinispan, just like in [this (stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27031481/use-infinispan-7-for-wildfly-8-1-0) post.

The only problem is the folder structure (on the server and in the downloaded .zip file alike) changed a lot and I do not have any clue of how to do this.

Furthermore I would like to do this via the cli console, getting the .zip folder from the local filesystem.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

At first you would need to download Wildfly/EAP modules. Get it from [here](http://downloads.jboss.org/infinispan/8.1.0.CR1/infinispan-as-embedded-modules-8.1.0.CR1.zip). Then you need to unpack it into @$WILDFLY_HOME/modules. Using `modules/system` is not recommended, since it is reserved for Wildfly-only stuff (custom modules should be placed directly under modules directory).

Could you tell me more about your use case? Do you use embedded or remote cache? How do you obtain a reference to CacheManager? And finally what are you trying to achieve with this upgrade?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help.

Unfortunately, i cannot tell you anything about the things you asked. I am totally new to this and currently it was my task as an intern to upgrade Infinispan. The only thing I was told, is security purpose. I will try this out next week, thank you for now